# Play Framework: Mixing Java and Scala controller/views

Tags: java, scala, playframework

There is a setting .enablePlugins(PlayScala) in the built.sbt file that sets my project to scala.

Now I want to use Java as well. I found that there are two versions of data.Form (play.data._ and import play.api.data._). So I used the fully qualified type for the parameter list.

```
@(loginForm: play.data.Form[User_LoginForm])

@import helpers._

@helper.form(action = routes.ApplicationJava.login(), 'id -> "loginForm") {
@helper.inputText(loginForm("username"))
@helper.inputPassword(loginForm("password"))
}
```

But now I have the same problem with the helper functions and I don't know what the fully qualified name for helper is so that they work with play.data.Form (Java).

Is there a way to use the helper functions for Java even when the project is set to scala?

Edit:

The error message for this line >> @helper.inputText(loginForm("username")) << is:

```
type mismatch; found : play.data.Form.Field required: play.api.data.Field
```

Edit:

Here is the corresponding part of my Java contoller.

```
public static Result showForm() {

    Form<User_LoginForm> userForm = play.data.Form.form(User_LoginForm.class);
    User_LoginForm ulf = new User_LoginForm();
    ulf.username = "abc";
    userForm = userForm.fill(ulf);

    return ok(views.html.userLoginJava.render(userForm));
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a special version of helpers to be used with Java (your template files are converted to Scala code...). Using play.data.Form with those helpers does not work? If you get a compilation/runtime error add it to your question

Comment: try changing to `@(loginForm: play.api.data.Form[User_LoginForm])`

Comment: play.api.data.Form is the standard for Scala. If I change it I get "error: incompatible types: play.data.Form<User_LoginForm> cannot be converted to play.api.data.Form<User_LoginForm>" error in my Java controller. "final static Form<User_LoginForm> loginForm = Form.form(User_LoginForm.class);" User_LoginForm is a Java class.

Comment: "Form<User_LoginForm> userForm = play.data.Form.form(User_LoginForm.class);" does not work with play.api.data.Form.

Comment: ok I  thought you are calling from scala controller.If you are importing helper then there is no need of doing helper dot in each field

Comment: Now I wrote "@inputText(loginForm("username"))" but get the error "not found: value inputText"

Comment: that error says you are using wrong form package are you sure  your `loginForm` is of type `play.data.Form[]` type and not of `play.api.data.Form[]`  and you have imported helper. And when you change your build you run a `play clean` command

Comment: I checked documentation (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Form) and in play.api.data.Form there is no "form()" method. The Java equivalent play.data.Form (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/index.html) has a method "form(java.lang.Class<T> clazz)".

Comment: I'm having the same error with a project, and find difficult to believe that nobody else has this problem.

Are you using by coincidence are you using IntelliJ Ultimate?

Answer (score 0):

PlayMagicForJava is supposed to implicitly convert your play.data.Form.Field into play.api.data.Field

```
implicit def javaFieldtoScalaField(jField: Field): Field
```

> Implicit conversion of a Play Java form Field to a proper Scala form Field.

[link to api](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.core.j.PlayMagicForJava$)

Comment: Please quote the necessary information of the given link into your answer to prevent loss of information by link rot.